# Installing NFS packages on Yocto

Tags: linux, embedded, nfs, yocto

I need to download nfs-common(package that need for NFS) on my Yocto system, but I don't understand how to do that.

I try apt-get and yum but that doesn't work.

Comment: Which embedded system? There tons of them. What OS/destitution do you use?

Comment: freescale TWR -LS1021A , kernel version :3.12.0

Comment: the result of the commend: cat /etc/issue.net , poky (yocto project...) 1.5. and uname -o , GNU/LINUX

Comment: try `apt-get install nfs-kernel-server`

Comment: "apt-get:command not found"

Comment: any suggestion? I think that the system knows the command wget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if your building your own system, then you need to add the required packages to your image. (I.e. add them to `IMAGE_INSTALL`).

If you're just running a pre-generated image, you could very well find it a lot harder...

You need to find the answer to the following questions:

- Do you have any package manager at all installed?

  - If you have; does your provider have any repositories that you can add? Otherwise you'll likely need to build the package yourself and transfer the required package (`rpm`, `ipk`, or `deb`) to your image manually.
  - If you don't have any package manager installed, you could still build a package and try to move and install all the files manually; though it would be a lot easier (and better for the future) to build your own image in that case.

As it was a Freescale system, I'd guess that you can find more information about the actual BSP at [FSL Community BSP](http://freescale.github.io/)

Comment: I look at the files in the folder /etc/init.d and there is a file "mountnfs.sh" , that can help? or that's not enough.. thank for your reply

Comment: Well, that file comes from the `initscripts` package, and doesn't really tell you if you have everything else that's needed for NFS mounts.

Though, I thought your question here was more about installing packages...